# jQuery not functioning as it should, prints alert instantly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Something's up with my JavaScript on my local website. I decided to test by making a button:

```
<button id="test">test</button>
```

and running:

```
$('#test').click(alert("hello"));
```

The issue is that the alert happens when I reload the page and not when I press the button. I have some AJAX running on the site and some PHP and the basics (HTML, CSS, JS).

```js
$('#test').click( function() { alert("hello"); } );


function showWords(chooseDiv,str,table) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById(chooseDiv).innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById(chooseDiv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getWords.php?filter="+str+"&table="+table,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="test">test</button>
```

### Update

I have attached a snippet to show the code which on here is working but not on my site.

Comment: Can you share some code with the problem happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your alert into `function () { alert (...); }` otherwise it is triggered immediately

```
$('#test').click( function() { alert("hello"); } );
```

To properly attach this event handler you can either 1) move it below the html markup, best before closing `</body>` tag, or 2) put it inside jQuery DOM ready listener and then leave it anywhere on your page (as far as it is below `jquery.js` itself), like below:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#test').click( function() { alert("hello"); } );
});
```

Comment: It now doesn't launch on reload now which is good, but the button still doesn't activate the alert. I've tried to add the command on the console and then it works. Could it be `AJAX` messing with my jquery?

Comment: Only if you do something to this button in the ajax callback like replacing it. Show more html and javascript if you can.

Comment: There really isn't much other code to add. I have `AJAX` calling a `MySQL` database using `PHP` on the page but for a different div and I have no other jquery than what you can see above in the snippet. I really don't see what could be causing it.

Comment: So I fixed by adding the jquery after the button instead of before. I think it's a bit of a temporary fix but it'll do. Thanks for your help, I'll set this as the answer.

Comment: Well, actually that's the fix you needed, because before it the element wasn't there in DOM to attach a click handler. You can move it below the html markup as you did or you can put it inside a document `ready` event listener which is common practice with jQuery. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the `alert()` function is run immediately. It is the same as doing this:

```
var val = alert("hello"); // var val = undefined;
$('#test').click(val);    // $('#test').click(undefined);
```

In order to run it only when the element is clicked you need to put it in a callback function, like so:

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

You can also define the callback function as a "normal" function and then pass it to the `.click()` method, like this:

```
function handleClick() {
    alert("hello");
}
$('#test').click(handleClick);
```

Callback functions are only run when they are called. In this case the `.click()` method will run it when the user clicks on the element.

In order to bind the click handler to the element the Javascript needs to be run *after* the HTML. You should do two things:

1. Wrap your jQuery stuff in the following:

   ```
   $(function () {
       // Put your jQuery code here...
   });
   ```
2. Include your Javascript at the bottom of the page. This will make sure that your HTML is indeed loaded, and it has the additional benefit of making your website appear to load faster; Javascript files stop the rendering of the website, and putting it at the bottom prevents this.

   ```
   <html>
       <head>...</head>
       <body>
           ...
           <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer.

Comment: @FrederikPetersen Det var så lidt.